# What is the relationship between UFW (firewall) being enabled and cron job running?

Tags: ajax, cron

I have a very specific problem on my server and can't wrap my head around it.
I use BackUpWordpress as a backup solution for my site.
Recently I noticed cron jobs were not firing properly to backup the files and database. When I manually used the backup option, the page refreshed without backuping my site.

In the console log I inspected the XHR request and noticed it returned an error, mentionning the firewall as a potential culprit.

I disabled UFW (firewall on my Ubuntu server) and it worked again.
Can someone explain to me the relation between the two? I don't understand why the firewall would cause problems with wp-cron.php and wp-ajax.php tasks.
Thanks!

Comment: How does the cron job work? Specifically, does it use a localhost address for the site or the external IP or domain name, and does the firewall allow access to that from the machine itself? Can you try making the cron request from a shell and does that work OK?

Comment: I can try but this is not a cron job I set up myself. It's a default way of working of the Wordpress CMS to do things like backups or post planification. Your comment put me on a track though. Maybe I should check that the firewall authorizes references to the server from the server itself. I thought that would be the case by default. I'll look into how to do that.